# Unix Shell command for removing each words between space and comma

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a string variable as

```
columns = "name string,age int,address string,dob timestamp"
```

I want to remove the datatypes. ie I want to remove the words coming after space and a comma. The output should be as

```
name,age,address,dob
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `bash` shell and  `extglob` shell option is available - see [pattern matching manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)

```
$ columns='name string,age int,address string,dob timestamp'
$ echo "${columns// +([^,])/}"
name,age,address,dob
```

With `sed`

```
$ echo "$columns" | sed 's/ [^,]*//g'
name,age,address,dob
```

With `awk` to process fields separated by `,`

```
$ echo "$columns" | awk -F, -v OFS="," '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){split($i,n," "); $i=n[1]}} 1' 
name,age,address,dob
```

If all columns contain two words separated by space, one can use space or comma as delimiter and filter out unwanted fields

```
$ echo "$columns" | awk -F' |,' -v OFS=',' '{print $1,$3,$5,$7}' 
name,age,address,dob
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both are working fine and it saved my time.